# Phrase Express not working with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I can't seem to get Phrase Express shortcuts/hotkeys to work in VS 2012. It works fine with VS 2010.

Has anyone come across this and found a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I needed to run Phrase Express with administrator privileges.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Does absolutely nothing, whether I run it as admin or not. Developer also hasn't answered my support request. Hmm. I'm on Win 10 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me. Does absolutely nothing, whether I run it as admin or not. Developer also hasn't answered my support request. Hmm. I'm on Win 10 64-bit.